# Role of the crystallographic point group on properties of tensorial elasticity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, symmetry, elasticity

If a space point group for a crystal is known, does this automatically define the elastic tensor symmetry of the material? What further implications can be found?

The crystallographic subgroups:

[image: from Wiki, Hermann–Mauguin notation]

For example, the numbers of the elastic tensor parameters *need not be known*, but certain relations must exist in order for the energy of the crystal to be positive definite, which is a consequence of the structure's stability. One such combinations of relations for a hexagonally symmetric elastic tensor is that

$$C_{44} > 0, \,\, C_{11} > | C_{12} |, \,\,\,\,\left(C_{11} + C_{12} \right) C_{33} > 2 C_{13}^2$$

So for Zn, which is of the point group $P6_3/\mathrm{mmm}$, has hexagonal structure, this automatically ensures the above case? Is there a situation in which this is not true? It is obvious that ANY hexagonal structure should have the above case but is there a general method for finding the additional constraints for say the differences between $P6mm$ and $P\bar{6}m2$?

Comment: I think http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53110/generic-born-stability-criteria has the answer you are looking for (stability wise). For the first question, yes, the symmetries of the stiffness tensor $C$ must mirror the symmetry of the lattice.

Comment: I was directed to a paper that goes through the general stability criterion of trigonal, hexagonal, ect (R. Cowley Phys Rev B. 1976). I suppose it answers my own question for the geometric classes, but not the subclasses(ie $PBmm$ vs $P\bar{6}m2$).